# How to get login history from beginning of time in Joomla?

Tags: authentication, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm using Joomla 2.5 at this time, and would like to see users log-in activities from the beginning of time. The data I would need will be *user name* and *log-in time*. How may I get the log-in activity log in Joomla? Are there any extensions available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a default Joomla feature.

You can find various extensions to do it in the Joomla Extensions Directory under Administration > Admin Reports
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-reports

One of note, and it's been updated in the past few weeks for Joomla 2.5 and 3.1, is LogMAN by Joomlatools
http://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/logman/overview

Comment: Thanks for your reply.There is any non commercial extension are available

Comment: If they're not listed in the Extensions Directory, chances are there's not any non-commercial ones. I see the non-commercial ones in the admin reports there are more for server logs than activity logging.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting my StackExchange answers in case there's an alternative years later...

Joomla 3 Action Log component was introduced in Joomla 3.9. This feature would now be where to find user logs, provided you've activated the logging system to record this data.

You can find out more at
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:User_Action_Logs

Comment: Also, check out joomla.stackexchange.com for Joomla specific questions and answers.